# I'm having errors in swift 2.1

Tags: swift, swift2

The error the I'm getting says

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
var recordSettings = [AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 ]
```

> 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use
>   ByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead.

```
 func getFileURL() -> NSURL {
    let path  = getCacheDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    return filePath!
```

> Cannot Force unwrap value of non-optional type 'NSURL'
>   error says -> Argument Labels '(contentsOfURL :, error:)' do not match
>   any available overloads.

```
SoundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: getFileURL(), error: &error)
```

Comment: I think the question title can really be a bit more specific.

Comment: Don't throw all your (unformatted) code at the wall. Ask ONE thing. Even better, think about that one thing and then ask about it.

Comment: im a new user to stackoverflow and swift coding. give me a break lol

Answer (score 1):

Well, the compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong.

For example:

the error the I'm getting says "type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

```
var recordSettings = [AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleLossless, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue, AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2, AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 ]
```

The type of `recordSettings` is ambiguous without more context. This means that the compiler isn't sure what the type of `recordSettings` should be... You need to tell it. Like this:

```
var recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleLossless, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue, AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2, AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 ]
```

And this:

```
'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use ByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead.
```

The above means exactly what it says. The method `stringByAppendingPathComponent` is unavailable and you should use `byAppendingPathComponent` on `NSURL` instead.

And this:

```
Cannot Force unwrap value of non-optional type 'NSURl'
```

Again it means exactly what it says. You can't force unwrap a non-optional type. "Force unwrap" means to put an `!` at the end of a variable.

The compiler is trying to help you write correct code.